# Create a dynamic array for use in grunt concat

Tags: json, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I need to concatenate a set files based on variables I have defined my package.json.

```
// package.json
...

"layouts": [
    { 
      "page": "home",
      "version": "a"
    },
    { 
      "page": "about",
      "version": "a" 
    },
    { 
      "page": "contact",
      "version": "b" 
    }
  ]

...
```

In grunt I am then building these into a JSON array and pumping it into the `src` parameter in my grunt-concat-contrib task.

```
// gruntfile.js
...

var package = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    targets = package.layouts,
    paths = [];

    for (var target = 0; target < targets.length; target++) {
        paths.push("layouts/" + targets[target]['page'] + "/" + targets[target]['version'] + "/*.php");
    };

    var paths = JSON.stringify(paths);

    grunt.log.write(paths); // Writing this to console for debugging

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            build: {
                src: paths,
                dest: 'mysite/Code.php',
                options: {
                    separator: '?>\n\n'
                }
            }
        }
    });

...
```

My issue is that the `paths` variable is not working inside of the `initConfig` when it is assigned to `JSON.stringify(paths)`.

If I manually input the array like the following that I copied from where I logged the paths variable to the console, it works!

`var paths = ["layouts/home/a/*.php","layouts/about/a/*.php","layouts/contact/b/*.php"];`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp. I fixed it, I didn't need to `JSON.stringify()` the array.

Final working gruntfile is below:

```
// gruntfile.js
...

var package = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    targets = package.layouts,
    paths = [];

for (var target = 0; target < targets.length; target++) {
    paths.push("layouts/" + targets[target]['page'] + "/" + targets[target]['version'] + "/*.php");
};

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        build: {
            src: paths,
            dest: 'mysite/Code.php',
            options: {
                separator: '?>\n\n'
            }
        }
    }
});

...
```